# Network profiles update button does not work on Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, linked-accounts

When trying to change username or account description on any other SE site, it does not update it on Area 51.

For example, my username here is `Peanut` but on Area 51 it is `Puzzles to Go`. *(don't ask)*

This happens even when clicking the update on all sites button.

Comment: 1) Many changes propagated on the SE asynchronously with some delay (in 1-2 days). 2) Area51 is an old, abandoned fork of the _very_ old SE engine. --> Wait a little bit and try to make a clear bugreport with many usable data (links, time, what you did and what you got, etc).

Comment: I have had this username for around 2 months now.

Comment: @Peanut Area 51 will never be synchronized, but this is by design.